# Chapter names in TOC spanning textwidth

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocbasic

I want to set `\@tocrmarg` to `0pt` in the case of `chapter` to have it spanning across the whole TOC. I am using the [tocbasic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic) package (successor of [tocstyle](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocstyle)), both are parts of [KOMA-Script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand{\suppresstext}[1]{}
\newcommand{\tocformatchapter}[1]{\large\textbf{#1}}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\chaptertocdepth,
  beforeskip=16pt,
  entryformat={\tocformatchapter},
  pagenumberformat={\suppresstext}
]{chapter}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `\@pnumwidth` is only the width of the page number box. The right margin of the entry text is given by `\@tocrmarg` independent from `\@pnumwidth`. So I think, you don't want `\@pnumwidth` to be set to 0pt but `\@tocrmarg`.

You could define your own entry style, that does not use `\@pnumwidth` and `\@tocrmarg`, using `\DefineTOCEntryStyle`. If you don't need a lot of configuration options this could be simple. And if you need configuration options but start with a copy of style `tocline` from `tocbasic.sty` this wouldn't be much work too.

But you can also use a simple hack. `entryformat` is executed to print the whole entry. So it is not to late to change `\rightskip` here. And execution of `entryformat` is local to the entry. So changing `\rightskip` here would not influence other entries:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\newcommand{\suppresstext}[1]{}
\newcommand{\tocformatchapter}[1]{\rightskip 0pt\large\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\chaptertocdepth,
  beforeskip=16pt,
  entryformat={\tocformatchapter},
  pagenumberbox=\suppresstext,
]{chapter}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\addchaptertocentry{}{Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter}
\addsectiontocentry{}{Section}
\addsectiontocentry{}{Section}
\addchaptertocentry{}{Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter Chapter}
\addsectiontocentry{}{Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section Section}
\addsectiontocentry{}{Section}
\addsectiontocentry{}{Section}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image: chapter entries with full width]

Note also: I've changed the `\addcontentsline` commands into `\addchaptertocentry` and `\addsectiontocentry` because you should also use the highest possible user interface.

Comment: Thank you! I applied it successfully at https://github.com/gi-ev/LNI-proceedings/blob/master/proceedings.tex#L155.